# How To Show Google map using Iframe

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsnIW.png)
I want to open a Google map on my website.
I want to use Google Maps on my own website, similar to how Google is used with a code like this: `src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"`, but I'm having trouble using Google Maps.

Comment: Please define "not working", and I imagine you would be better off using Google's supported [embedding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started) rather than linking to the homepage (which they may actively prevent being loaded externally)

Comment: Please provide the error you're encountering. There's no such thing as "not working" only, you must provide some information about the error you're getting to give us enough information to help you.

Comment: I want to use Google Maps on my own website, similar to how Google is used with a code like this: `src="https://www.google.com/search?igu=1"`, but I'm having trouble using Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

On google maps website, click on top right hamburguer menu -> Shared map -> Insert map and there are code, example:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As is in example

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d11200.675829730526!2d-75.6876061!3d45.42609535!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x4cce04ff4fe494ef%3A0x26bb54f60c29f6e!2sParliament+Hill!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1528808935681" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

This will work. All you need is to change the location. You can use something like this:

https://www.maps.ie/create-google-map/

Just fill the place you want to show and iframe is ready to use.